# Remove timestamp from a discord embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to modify an embed from an existing message, How do I delete or remove the timestamp from the message

```py
@commands.command()
async def remove_timestamp(self, ctx, msg: discord.MessageConverter):
   embed = msg.embeds[0]
   embed.timestamp = None #error raised here
   await msg.edit(embed=embed)
```

Similar code worked when I tried to update color of the embeds or change the timestamp, but removing the timestamp raises an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting properties of embeds to `None` or removing it can be done with `discord.Embed.Empty`

```py
embed.timestamp = discord.Embed.Empty
```

This is the default value used by discord.py if you don't specify it manually.

References:

1. [Empty](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=empty#discord.Embed.Empty)
2. [Embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=empty#discord.Embed)